# Trying to put property in protocol

Tags: ios, objective-c, properties, mapkit, protocols

**Can someone explain the basics of how one would put a property in a protocol in order to access it's value across different view controllers?**

**Specifically**, I am trying to put the MKMapView property into a protocol. I have two view controllers:

1. Map View Controller (Inside it is 2. Table List View Controller)
2. Table List View Controller

In order to be able to select the post in the table list view controller that corresponds the annotation in the map view controller, I need to be able to access the map view in map view controller. This is where I thought protocols would come in handy.

**Map View Controller .h**

```
@protocol MapViewDelegate <MKMapViewDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet MKMapView *mapView;

@end

@interface PAWWallViewController : UIViewController <MapViewDelegate, ...>

...

@end
```

**Map View Controller .h**

```
...
@synthesize mapView = _mapView
...
```

**Table View Controller .h**

```
@interface PAWWallPostsTableViewController : PFQueryTableViewController <MapViewDelegate...>

...
```

**Table View Controller . m**

```
...
@synthesize mapView;
...

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // call super because we're a custom subclass.
    [super tableView:tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

    PFObject *object = [self.objects objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    PAWPost *post = [[PAWPost alloc] initWithPFObject:object];

    [mapView setCenterCoordinate: post.coordinate animated:YES];

    [mapView selectAnnotation:post animated:YES];

    NSLog(@"MAP VIEW: %@", mapView); // STILL NULL
}
```

Comment: Please include the full text of the error you are seeing.

Comment: A protocol doesn't make a property magically available, it simply makes it easier to reference without using another include.  To reference a property you need a pointer to the object containing the property.

Comment: I updated it. After synthesizing in both the .m files it now sends no error. But self.mapView returns null in log. I added the synthesis because I had warning saying that the auto property synthesis would not synthesize property mapView. Before I added this it sent the error: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<PAWWallViewController 0x17594100> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key mapView.'
***

Comment: @HotLicks Examples on how I would point to the object containing the property?

Comment: First you decide which object it is, then you copy the pointer to the object.

Comment: Sorry I'm a beginner I guess... :/ And haven't worked with protocols before. Code would be super appreciated.

Comment: It has nothing to do with protocols.  You want to reference a value.  It's in an object.  You need a pointer to that object.  It's that simple.  (And if you don't understand this you shouldn't be programming in Objective-C.  It's not a beginner's language.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a background on properties: [Encapsulating Data](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/EncapsulatingData/EncapsulatingData.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011210-CH5-SW2).

In short, properties are a quick way to define a getter method, a setter method and an instance variable (also called an ivar).

If you think about it, the non-auto-synthesizing properties in protocols is the correct behavior, it's just a little surprising at first. Protocols define an interface, but never creates code.

In your example the protocol:

```
@protocol MapViewDelegate <MKMapViewDelegate>
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet MKMapView *mapView;
@end
```

creates an interface for `-mapView` and `-setMapView:`, but doesn't create the implementation for those methods.

There are a few ways to get the needed methods in the `@implementation`.

1. Declare `@synthesize mapView;` in the `@implementation` of any class which implements  `MapViewDelegate`. *You already discovered this*. BTW: I would recommend `@synthesize mapView = _mapView;` because it's how auto synthesize names the ivar.
2. Declare `@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet MKMapView *mapView;` in the `@interface` of any class which implements `MapViewDelegate`.
3. Create the instance methods `- (MKMapView *)mapView` and `- (void)setMapView:(MKMapView *)mapView`. This is the old manual route for creating properties. In addition to defining the getter and setter, you will need to create an ivar to hold the value. *Note: I only included this for completeness sake, it's not a recommendation.*

Comment: Thanks! I implemented the first way to to that using @synthesize mapView = _mapView; in my wall view controller. I now get a value of course but I still need to work on getting that value across to the table view controller that still returns null.

Comment: @teenyton - "but I still need to work on getting that value across to the table view controller that still returns null" - putting a property in a protocol does not share it, it simply says that any class implementing the protocol must provide such a property. The properties in your two classes are independent, setting one won't affect the other.